# Uniqueness of Regular Borel measures on the Baire sets

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having problems proving the following theorem:

Theorem: If two regular Borel measures agree on all Baire sets, then they agree
on all Borel sets.

I have shown that $\mu(C) = \nu^*(C)$ for all compact sets, where 
$\nu^*(C) = inf\{\nu(E) : C \subseteq E \in \mathcal{B_O}\}$, $\mathcal{B_O}$ denotes the Baire sets, and $\nu = \mu_{|\mathcal{B_O}}$ is the Baire contraction of $\mu$. So obviously two regular Borel measures  agreeing on Baire sets, agree on the compact sets. But how do i extend this uniqueness to ALL borel sets?

Book(Halmos) says to use this theorem;

Theorem: If $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of all finite disjoint unions of compact sets, then $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \mathcal{B}$.

(If $\mathcal{F_O}$ is the collection of all finite disjoint unions of 
sets of compact $G_\delta$'s, then $\sigma(\mathcal{F_O}) = \mathcal{B_O}$)

Where $\mathcal{B}$ = $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ are the Borel sets.

Thanks in advance.